# Wifi doesn't work after hibernate but DOES work after suspend

Tags: wireless, suspend, hibernate

I run Ubuntu 13.10 (though on 13.04 situation was the same) on Thinkpad E125 laptop

I have very common problem - there were no WiFi after suspend. I've googled the problem and find solution that works perfectly - http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/fix-wireless-or-wired-network-not.html - after following those recommendation I have probably 100 suspend/wake-up cycles - WiFi always worked

But this fix didn't affect hibernate - now I have 100% times not working wifi after hibernate. If after hibernate I go to suspend and back - wifi start working again.

Can some please advise the way to apply that patch to hibernate

Answer (score 5):

Try `sudo killall NetworkManager`, as suggested in [Network devices unmanaged after resume from hibernation in Ubuntu Gnome 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375077/network-devices-unmanaged-after-resume-from-hibernation-in-ubuntu-gnome-13-10) . 
It works fine for me!

Answer (score 3):

This issue seems to be caused by bug [#1184262](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd-shim/+bug/1184262) . It is not related to the networking as such, but to power management.

The workaround I found was to create a file with: `sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_network` and paste the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Tell Network Manager that resume was successful

case "$1" in
       thaw)
         nmcli nm sleep false
         ;;
esac
```

Then, save and close the file and enter `sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_network`.

Comment: this solution messed up my laptop for a minute.  I had to restart in recovery mode because /etc/pm/sleep/d is mounted as read only so I couldn't just delete the file as root when it completely tanked my network manager