# Network devices unmanaged after resume from hibernation in Ubuntu Gnome 13.10

Tags: gnome, network-manager, hibernate

After confirmation that hibernation/resume worked well with `sudo pm-hibernate`, I enabled hibernatation on `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` to get the option in the session menu. Unfortunately, every time I hibernate this way, the network devices are all set to `unmanaged` and I have to reboot to get them work again.

Strangely, this problem doesn't happen when I use the command `sudo pm-hibernate` or when I just suspend. Does the hibernate menu item use a different command than `pm-hibernate`? Or maybe with different options? How can I make it work properly?

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue. `killall NetworkManager` is a workaround you can use.

Comment: Indeed, this is a good workaround. However, I'm hoping that there is a way to configure hibernation properly to avoid the issue completely.