# Internet connection not working in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, internet, 15.04

My internet connection is not working in Ubuntu 15.04

I kept the ethernet cable plugged-in during installation.

Later when I started Ubuntu and tried to connect to internet using Firefox, I received the error message: `Cannot connect to the internet`.

The network tray icon displays a Wi-Fi status.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

I have often faced issues with Networks in Ubuntu.

Some of the solutions which **may** help you:

1. [Network manager indicator missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159812/network-manager-indicator-missing)
2. Try restarting the network manager with:

   ```
   sudo service network-manager restart
   ```
3. [Network devices unmanaged after resume from hibernation in Ubuntu Gnome 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375077/network-devices-unmanaged-after-resume-from-hibernation-in-ubuntu-gnome-13-10)

Another possible issue could be that the driver is not installed, in which case you would need to go to "Additional Drivers" and install the appropriate driver.
For more details on that you can refer here: 
[How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers)